# How to read local text file in JavaScript automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I've been searching on the Internet to find a way to read local text file in JavaScript automatically.

However, I only found that most of the way is to creating an input type="file" and choose the text file manually from the computer.

Since I want to read a number of data from a local text file(.txt) automatically whenever I reload the website, so that I could perform some searching of data in my website.

Is that any way that I can read local txt file automatically with JavaScript?

Comment: The browsers won't allow this - it's a security risk.  Imagine a browser reading files at whim off your PC - sooner or later it's going to hit a file of passwords, or credit card numbers, or...

Comment: ... your "pron" collection. Instead why not fetch the file when needed from a server?

Comment: Store your data in local storage or cookies instead of in a file if you need to 
 refer to it later.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate of a question marked as a duplicate :)